# Using Lambda expression from a separate class in SELECT clause of LINQ query c# Projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to have the select query projection to a lambda expression in Entity framework..

In repo class

```
database.Employees.Where(s => s.EmpID == curEmp.ID)
               .Select(s => new EmployeeModel
                   {
                       Value = s.Name,
                       Text = s.ID
                       // I have 40 fields and 10 join table projections here so much code
                   });
```

Since I have many fields to project, so created a separate class with the lambda expressions for those long select projections.

```
public class ProjectionQueries
{
      public static readony Fun<Employee, EmployeeModel> GetEmployeeAsModel = (emp) 
            => new EmployeeModel
             {
                Value = s.Name,
                Text = s.ID...        
                ... 
                ..
                ..
                Address = new AddressModel{.....},
                Country = new CountryModel{.....}
              };
}
```

Then called the above lambda expression from the select clause of the repository method.

```
database.Employees.Where(s => s.EmpID == curEmp.ID)
               .Select(x => ProjectionQueries.GetEmployeeAsModel(x));
```

This way it is well segregated the code. But when I do this I get an error saying

```
The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of the System.Func<*,*>. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead.
```

Can't use this way to make my code less in the repository class. ?

Comment: `GetEmployeeAsModel` should be an `Expression<Func<....>>` and used like `.Select(GetEmployeeAsModel)`

Comment: Or use an auto-mapper to go from Employee to EmployeeModel without having to write 40 props

Comment: Why are you doing manual joins? EF should give you navigation-properties and `.Include()` already.

Answer (score 2):

You could separate this out as a [static extension method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```
 public static class EmployeeExtensions{ 
     public static IQueryable<EmployeeModel> AsEmployeeModels(this IQueryable<Employee> emps){
         return emps.Select(emp=> new EmployeeModel
                     {
                        Value = emp.Name,
                        Text = emp.ID... 
                      });
        }
    }
```

and use it as:

```
database.Employees.Where(s => s.EmpID == curEmp.ID).AsEmployeeModels();
```

Comment: It is worst usage when not all fields from database are needed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Then don't use EF and use `SqlDataReader` directly.

Comment: @Dai, In comments of original question is the right answer. It is common practice how to optimise EF queries.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In my experience the actual query execution-plan on the DB server matters more than just reducing selected columns: selecting a subset of columns makes _zero_ performance difference if the query cannot be satisfied by any `INDEX`'s `INCLUDE` columns so there'll be a physical table row read anyway - which is why I consider "optimizing" EF Linq queries by removing unused columns to be a waste of time (and causes more work when you later discover you need them..). And if you use anonymous-types then you can't return them from a method (it's a very poorly designed feature, imo).

Comment: @Dai, well I have different feeling when start optimising such projects. In one case they forgot that they fetch not needed blobs (schema changed), in other they fetch everything to check single integer field, in another case someone added `Include` at the top of the query. Everything counts in high load applications and if such practice everywhere in the project - everything is slow. SQL Server uses more memory and CPU than needed, through network passed unwanted data. We can scale APP server,  but SQL Server...

Comment: This is a valid answer. The  question ask to reuse a projection and extension method can do this.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I edited my answer to operate on IQueryable and that won't fetch all fields - only the ones you specify/project.

Comment: @GokulPanigrahi, much better.

Answer (score 0):

The @gokul-panigrahi answer show a solution with extension method, that I advice to use because I found the syntax smoothest.

---

The error is :

> The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of the **System.Func<*,*>**. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead.

The error indicate EF Core can't translate `System.Func<*,*>` to SGBD language. EF Core client evaluation. A solution is to execute the untranslatable part in client :

```cs
database.Employees
    // 1) Prepare Query
    .Where(s => s.EmpID == curEmp.ID)
    // 2) Execute query on server
    .AsEnumerable() 
    // 3) Next is execute in client
    .Select(x => ProjectionQueries.GetEmployeeAsModel(x));
```

See the ms-doc for more information about [Client vs Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation)

But client evaluation could result in [poor performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#unsupported-client-evaluation). In your case, if the projection can limit the number of column read in database (and limit the data transmit on network).

A other solution, it is to modify the type of `GetEmployeeAsModel` :

```cs
public static readony Expression<Fun<Employee, EmployeeModel>> GetEmployeeAsModel = ...
```

Thus EF Core can try translate the expression to SGBD's language. Try because the expression can use some term untranslatable like `Func<*,*>`.

---

What is the difference between `Func` and `Expression<Func>`?

A `Func` is delegate (trivially a pointer to a zone code in memory). EF Core don't know how translate a delegate.

A `Expression` is a specific structure of instruction, that is possible to explore :

```cs
Expression<Func<int,int>> expression = (x) => x % 2;

// Explore the expression
var operation = expression.Body as BinaryExpression;
var leftPart = operation.Left as ParameterExpression;
var rightPart = operation.Right as ConstantExpression;

// Translate
Console.WriteLine("@" + leftPart.Name);
// @x
Console.WriteLine(operation.NodeType);
// modulo
Console.WriteLine(rightPart.Value);
// 2
```

EF Core do this to translate the expression to SGBD's language, but sometime the expression contains a term unknown by EF Core. Then this produce a error like above.